# @property not persisting?, Sound not playing

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-audio

In a (file:Sound.m / method: setSound) I have this, which successfully sets and plays the sound ( it would seem ).

```
  [self setTheSound:&thisSoundID];
  AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(*(self.TheSound));
```

However, when called outside that method. I do not hear anything. Though I know it gets called from the NSLog. ( file:Sound.m / method: playSound )

```
- (void) playSound
{
    NSLog(@"Called playSound");
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(*(self.TheSound));
}
```

Here is the property setting on ( file:Sound.h / method: playSound )

```
@property SystemSoundID *TheSound;
```

Comment: Can you add the implementation of `setTheSound:` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not store the *address* of the sound ID but the sound ID itself
in the property (i.e., remove the `*`):

```
@property SystemSoundID theSound;
```

and then use it as

```
[self setTheSound:thisSoundID];
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(self.theSound);
```

In your case, `self.theSound` is the address of the *local variable* `thisSoundID`.
As soon as you leave the function where this variable  is declared, that memory
location might be reused for something else, and referring to it is "undefined
behaviour".

(Side note: for instance variables and properties, use names starting with a 
lowercase letter.)